# Python - adding to a dictionary, finding the largest value

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm taking two lists of tuples, doing some calculations and creating a dictionary, or at least trying to, so that I can find the character with the largest percentage.

```
    dict_original = dict(original_list)
    for c, p in new_list:
        if c in dict_original and dict_original[c] < p:
            diff = p - dict_original[c]
            output = {c:round(diff,3)}
            print output
```

The output i'm getting is something like this:

```
{'o': 0.026}
{'x': 0.046}
{'t': 0.037}
{'/': 0.038}
{'p': 0.037}
{'s': 0.038}
```

All I want is the character with the largest percentage; 'x', in this case. I've been unsuccessful using `max` so far.
I know, my output seems to be a bunch of dictionaries, that's why i'm asking for some help here.

Thanks!

Comment: remove print output from the loop,it will print the last greater one

Comment: @yodish care to add more context to your question, like what is `orignal_list` like, and what is `new_list`, and what are you trying to do with all the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your data it is hard to give you proper guidance.

You are not creating a new dictionary of all the results just a dict per result which is being discarded. You can create a complete dictionary using a dict comprehension, e.g. this is equivalent to your for loop:

```
do = dict_original
output = {c: round(p-do[c], 3) for c, p in new_list if do.get(c, float('inf')) < p}
```

To get the maximum value from this dict then as pointed out by @batman:

```
max(output, key=output.get)
```

Would return `'x'`

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `max` a `key` argument:

```
bar = max(foo, key=foo.get)
```

That will give you the key with the largest value.

Comment: `key=foo.get` would be sufficient.

Comment: I think that the `lambda` expression makes it a bit clearer what's going on though. Or am I imaging that?

Comment: Yes, you are imagining that. `.get()` is explicit, whereas an anonymous function is more verbose and has to be read to be understood.